# XSLT - Set Attribute based on Processing Instructions

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0

is there a possiblity to set an Attribute based on a Processing Instruction. We are using XLST 1.0 and i have following XML File:

```xml
<body>
    <div>
        Text
    </div>
    <div>
        <?class-start type="blue" ?>
        <span>
            <div>           
                Text1
            </div>
        </span>
        <?class-end type="blue" ?>
    </div>

    <div>
        <?class-start type="green" ?>
        <span>
            <div>
                <?class-end type="green" ?>
                Text2
            </div>
        </span>         
    </div>


    <div>       
        <span>
            <?class-start type="red" ?>
            <div>               
                Text3
            </div>
            <div>           
                Text4
            </div>
            <div>               
                Text5
            </div>
            <div>               
                Text6
            </div>
            <?class-end type="red" ?>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

And i want to transform it to following XML File:

```
<body>
    <div>
        Text
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="blue">
            <div class="blue">          
                Text1
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <?class-start type="green" ?>
        <span class="green">
            <?class-end type="green" ?>
            <div>           
                Text2
            </div>
        </span>     
    </div>


    <div>   
        <span>
            <div class="red">

                Text3
            </div>
            <div  class="red">

                Text4
            </div>
            <div  class="red">

                Text5
            </div>
            <div  class="red">

                Text6
            </div>
        </span> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Is it possible to transform it like that with using XSLT 1.0, or should i use a littel Programm (Java or something else) to transform it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does the output still have `<?class-start type="green" ?>`? And as you mention "a little program" and Java, why are you restricted to XSLT 1.0 in the Java world where Saxon 9 provides XSLT 2.0 and 3.0?

Comment: I want to use XSLT 1.0, but if there is no opportunity to do this in XSLT 1.0 i have to write an Programm in Java or something else.  I cant use Saxon because of the Licence.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very efficient, and also assumes you don't have over-lapping `class-start` and `class-end` processing instructions, but here is one way you could achieve this in XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[count(preceding::processing-instruction('class-start')) = count(preceding::processing-instruction('class-end')) + 1]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(substring-after(preceding::processing-instruction('class-start')[1], '='), '&quot;', ''))" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('class-start')|processing-instruction('class-end')" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```